# pyspark: filtering and extract struct through ArrayType column

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark 2.2 and has the following schema

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- metadata: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

and data

```
+----+----------------------------------------------+
|col1|col2                                          |
+----+----------------------------------------------+
|A   |[[id1, [k -> v1]], [id2, [k2 -> v5, k -> v2]]]|
|B   |[[id3, [k -> v3]], [id4, [k3 -> v6, k -> v4]]]|
+----+----------------------------------------------+
```

`col2` is a complex structure. It's an array of struct and every struct has two elements, an `id` string and a `metadata` map. (that's a simplified dataset, the real dataset has 10+ elements within struct and 10+ key-value pairs in the `metadata` field).

I want to form a query that returns a dataframe matching my filtering logic (say `col1 == 'A'` and `col2.id == 'id2'` and `col2.metadata.k == 'v2'`).

The result would look like this, the filtering logic can match **at most one** struct within the array so in the second column it's just one struct instead of an array of one struct

```
+----+--------------------------+
|col1|col2_filtered             |
+----+--------------------------+
|A   |[id2, [k2 -> v5, k -> v2]]|
+----+--------------------------+
```

I know how to achieve this through `explode`, but the issue is `col2` normally has over 100+ structs and there will be at most one matching my filtering logic so I don't think `explode` is a scalable solution.

Can someone tells me how to do that, thanks in advance!

Below is the code block for setting things up.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType, MapType

schema = StructType([
    StructField('col1', StringType(), True),
    StructField('col2', ArrayType(
        StructType([
            StructField('id', StringType(), True),
            StructField('metadata', MapType(StringType(), StringType()), True)
        ])
    ))
])

data = [
    ('A', [('id1', {'k': 'v1'}), ('id2', {'k': 'v2', 'k2': 'v5'})]),
    ('B', [('id3', {'k': 'v3'}), ('id4', {'k': 'v4', 'k3': 'v6'})])
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: you can try a UDF:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.filter(
    F.udf(lambda x: any([y.id == 'id2' and 'k' in y.metadata.keys() for y in x]), 'boolean')('col2')
).withColumn(
    'col2',
    F.udf(lambda x: [y for y in x if y.id == 'id2' and 'k' in y.metadata.keys()][0], 'struct<id:string,metadata:map<string,string>>')('col2')
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+----+--------------------------+
|col1|col2                      |
+----+--------------------------+
|A   |[id2, [k2 -> v5, k -> v2]]|
+----+--------------------------+
```

---

You can cast the columns to JSON and check if col2 contains the desired JSON:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.filter(
    (F.col('col1') == 'A') &
    F.to_json('col2').contains(
        F.to_json(
            F.struct(
                F.lit('id2').alias('id'),
                F.create_map(F.lit('k'), F.lit('v2')).alias('metadata')
            )
        )
    )
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+----+------------------------------------+
|col1|col2                                |
+----+------------------------------------+
|A   |[[id1, [k -> v1]], [id2, [k -> v2]]]|
+----+------------------------------------+
```

If you just want to keep the matching struct in col2, you can replace it using `withColumn`:

```
df3 = df2.withColumn(
    'col2', 
    F.struct(
        F.lit('id2').alias('id'),
        F.create_map(F.lit('k'), F.lit('v2')).alias('metadata')
    )
)

df3.show()
+----+----------------+
|col1|            col2|
+----+----------------+
|   A|[id2, [k -> v2]]|
+----+----------------+
```

Comment: thanks @mcd for the quick response. In fact the dataset for this post is a simplified version, the real one has over 10+ elements in the struct and 10+ key-value pairs in the metadata map. The first solution can be achieved through `array_contains` I believe but that's not what I want, I want the only one struct that matches my filtering logic instead of an array that contains the matching one. For the second solution, it's impossible for me to **construct** a struct with the matching values because I'm blind on other values within the struct. Can you modify your answer to reflect that. thx

Comment: Not sure if you have understood my answer fully, but the second solution depends on the first solution. The `df2` variable comes from the first part. Does that help?

Comment: I get your answer, I'm afraid it fails when I have extra key-value pairs in the `metadata`. I edited my post to reflect the changes.

Comment: That's a bit harder. tbh `filter` in Spark 2.4 should be a better fit for this sort of tasks. For Spark 2.2 you'll probably need to rely on this kind of trick in my answer, or if you don't mind a bit of performance hit, using a UDF.

Comment: @FrancisYL I added a UDF solution. see if that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the solution from @mck, I tried another three ways after searching that all get the desired result.

1. Filtering using `udf` and returns the matching struct

```
df.filter(df.col1 == 'A') \
  .select(df.col1, udf(lambda a: [s for s in a if s.id == 'id2' and s.metadata['k'] == 'v2'], df.schema['col2'].dataType)('col2')[0].alias('col2_filtered')) \
  .na.drop('any')
```

2. Filtering using `udf` and get the index of the matching struct

```
df.filter(df.col1 == 'A') \
  .select(df.col1, df.col2.getItem(udf(lambda a: [i for i, s in enumerate(a) if s.id == 'id2' and s.metadata['k'] == 'v2'], ArrayType(IntegerType(), True))(df.col2)[0]).alias('col2_filtered')) \
  .na.drop('any')
```

3. Filtering using `expr`, this is a feature in Spark 2.4 so can be a candidate for future upgrades

```
df.filter(df.col1 == 'A') \
  .select(df.col1, expr("filter(col2, s -> s.id == 'id2' AND s.metadata['k'] == 'v2')").getItem(0).alias('col2_filtered')) \
  .na.drop('any')
```